# ASP.NET Core disable Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have .NET Core MVC web application where during creation I set Windows authentication. Now I want to disable Windows authentication and enable anonymous authentication (I have my own authentication mechanism). Here is what I have set in my config file

> .vs\config\applicationhost.config

```
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
```

My problem is that when I reopen the solution and run it, the config is changing to:

```
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
```

How it's possible that something is changing the config and what should I do to prevent this change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is managed by Visual Studio and it is being regenerated.

To disable Windows Authentication, you must change project settings is Visual Studio. This setting is stored in the **launchSettings.json** file and Visual Studio generates **applicationhost.config** for the IIS Express process - when ASP.NET Core is hosted in the IIS Express.

Details about this configuration are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how I missed entries in launchSettings.json :)