# How to disable windows authentication only for Web API inside a .net core MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core MVC web application and I have set windows authentication for that project. 
Now I have added an API controller in the same project and for which I don't want authentication.
Is it possible to disable windows authentication only for API ?
The reason why I have created the application with windows authentication is to just log the current user details who is accessing my application via browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core disable Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029878/asp-net-core-disable-windows-authentication)

Comment: I have seen that post but what I understood is he need to disable the authentication for the whole app and not for just API separately.

Comment: Sorry if my suggestion is uninformed but can't you just decorate the API controller with [AllowAnonymous] ?

Comment: Allowanonymous will just bypass authorization but not authentication..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending several hours I have found the following solution:
 In launchsettings.json set following values

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
```

Add the following line inside startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

add

```
[Authorize]
```

attribute in controller where we need to get the user name
    using namespace

```
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization)
```

Thus, I am able to hit the API without giving authorization and I am able to get the current user details in the MVC controller.

This one helped me in figuring out the solution : https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2913